# How to alter an existing Views display?

Tags: views

I know in order to create views displays you simply declare it as:

```
  $view = views_get_view('AN_EXISING_VIEW', TRUE);


  $handler = $view->new_display('page', 'YOUR_DISPLAY_NAME', 'YOUR_DISPLAY_MACHINE_NAME');
  $handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'TITLE';
  ...
  views_save_view($view);
```

You can do this in `hook_enable` in your install file or using `hook_views_default_views`

All I need is however to programatically alter an existing view display of a Workbench Moderation module (workbench_moderation): 'YOUR_DISPLAY_NAME' and 'DEFAULT' in order add other fields and permissions on those fields.

My questions are:

1. How do I effectivelly get the specific display: e.g. `$views->get_display`?
2. How do I save it so that will not mess the views caches?

Comment: I have impression that there are to many questions here, really. And do you want to alter view provided by another module (allowing user to alter your alterations), or override what user edited?

Comment: @Mołot, I have reedited for better understanding, yes I need to alter the view provided by workbench_moderation by adding fields to its display.

Comment: Do you need to do that after the query executed or do you need to alter the query as well?

Comment: Drupont seems to be the exact use case provided as an example on API page. Hope my answer is what you have in mind. Anyway I'm still a bit unclear if that's what you meant, and it seems @ЕлинЙ. share some of my doubts, so please confirm or clarify again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views provided by a module are defined using [`hook_views_default_views`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views/7) - and as almost anything, they can be modified using "alter" version of this hook, namely [`hook_views_default_views_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views_alter/7):

Alter default views defined by other modules.

> This hook is called right before all default views are cached to the database. It takes a keyed array of views by reference.
>
> Example usage to add a field to a view:

```
$handler =& $view->display['DISPLAY_ID']->handler;
// Add the user name field to the view.
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Author';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_user'] = 1;
```

Source code from API help page linked above.

Comment: @Drupont They are called on install, really - as you are modifying default views, there is no need to call them repeatedly, they are needed only once and then there is view cached in views' cache and that's all to it ;)